# How to manipulate position of mask layer using python

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, masking

I'm using Blender 2.78 and playing around with making different video transition effects. I want to automate the dynamics of a mask layer(rectangle as seen below) and it all work fine if I add keyframe>move rectangle>add keyframe however facing a hard time in finding how I could manipulate the position of the rectangle from the scripts. Already tried to work with `bpy.ops.transform`, `bpy.data.masks['Mask bar'].layers.active.select` but it seems that none of them has a member or function that gives me access to the position of the rectangle.

Not after something big, just couple of pointers on what object would store the data I'm after.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get the position of the mask as a whole, but you can access the coordinates of each individual *point* of the mask.

You can access the mask with:

```
bpy.data.masks['Mask']
```

And then the `layer` within the mask:

```
bpy.data.masks['Mask'].layers['MaskLayer']
```

Then you have access to the `splines` in that layer, which are the curves of the mask. In this case I am accessing the first spline:

```
bpy.data.masks['Mask'].layers['MaskLayer'].splines[0]
```

Which then leads you to the spline's `points`. The `points` have a vector called `co` (coordinates) which store the x and y position of that point. By looping over all the `points` in the mask and altering the `co[0]`(x) or `co[1]`(y) you can move the mask:

```
mask = bpy.data.masks['Mask'].layers['MaskLayer'].splines[0]
for point in mask.points:
    point.co[0] += 0.1
```