# Scale mask from given control point

Tags: uv-image-editor, masking

I have a **triangle** shaped mask, and want to scale it from one of its points. Now, I am struggling how to do it precisely.

1. There is no coordinates of control point, so can't put 2D cursor there, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected* also doesn't exist
2. There is no pivot option like *Active element* from 3D view.

I was thinking about placing 2D cursor at given coordinates and create point here, but even this is impossible, because point is created by mouse and I can't click with such precision.

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65238/how-to-manipulate-position-of-mask-layer-using-python @RayMairlot Could you help here on how to get only location of selected point?